# Angular Transclusion

Tags: angularjs, transclusion

See this plnkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/theggRtJlbFj1H4zVUKU?p=preview

using the $compile service, I need to have dirC nested inside dirB.
The output should be

```
DirB
DirC
```

I thought this was bug since dirC directive and controller was never fired, so the Angular group said to use transclusion.

Ok, so I use transclusion and dirC and dirB is never added to the DOM.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directive C is included inside the directive B. But the only visible text in both templates is inside the div which has the directive `ng-transclude`. So the textual content is replaced by the transcluded HTML: the directive C in the case if `<dir-b>`, and nothing in the case of `<dir-c>`.

Here's your example with fixed templates to show you that it works fine: https://plnkr.co/edit/FRtMA3h0Caredc4staW8?p=preview

Like ng-view, ng-transclude is a placeholder which means: replace the content of this element by the one inside the body of the directive.

Comment: Great! thanks for the comment about ng-transclude is like ng-view...that makes a little more sense.